# $(BuildConfiguration) in Azure Pipeline (VSTS) Not Working For Project

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In my VSTS build, I have a powershell script that runs the following

`Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildConfiguration]DeployDebug"`

A few steps later, I execute the build with a Visual Studio Build step with `$(BuildConfiguration)` in the `Configuration` text box.   The build completes successfully and 3 of my projects end up on the build agent machine as

`C:\agent\_work\31\s\src\MySolution\ProjectX\Bin\DeployDebug`

However, the fourth one will not build in this way and only ends up as

`C:\agent\_work\31\s\src\MySolution\ProjectZ\Bin\Debug`

All four projects have a configuration set up for `DeployDebug` that looks like:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'DeployDebug|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\DeployDebug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport><CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Is there any other place that the project needs to be configured so that it builds to `/DeployDebug` like the others?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that they *all* have `<OutputPath>bin\DeployDebug\</OutputPath>`, and that nothing else anywhere in the csproj file is overriding `OutputPath`?

Comment: @DanielMann I ended up having to edit the solution properties and platforms for those projects

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by editing the .sln file and adding the missing build configurations

```
GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
    {9999F999-9B1B-4950-9B69-613F5367CD35}.DeployDebug|Any CPU.Build.0 = DeployDebug|Any CPU
    {9999F999-9B1B-4950-9B69-613F5367CD35}.DeployRelease|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = DeployRelease|Any CPU
```

I was in a text editor looking for obvious differences when I found this, but I am fairly certain this could have been done in Visual Studio by right clicking the solution, selecting "Properties" and then looking at the "Configuration Properties" property sheet.

[image]